# Dispatching AWT Event With No User Input

Tags: java, awt

I need to dispatch an event in AWT in the constructor of a panel. I need to do this because the `AWT-EventQueue` needs to aquire a `ReentrantLock` and release it when the user clicks a button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an easy solution:

[invokeLater()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: ok, i misunderstand you. But for AWT use `EventQueue.invokeLater( runnable )`

Comment: It seems the two are interchangeable. At least, I don't see any immediate problems using one in one place and the other in another place, even though I know it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
AWTEvent e = ... 
this.dispatchEvent( e );
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent( e );
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().processKeyEvent(this, (KeyEvent)e);
```

Comment: How then do I go about responding to the event?